# Reading ICNS files to BufferedImage[] object

Tags: java, bufferedimage, apache-tika, icns

I have an ICNS file with multiple icons in it. I need to convert it to an array of BufferedImage objects using Java code. I did this using commons-imaging library by apache. It turns out I cannot use that library within my organization. Is there any other library that could be used to accomplish the task? I was having a look at apache-tika, but I could not find a way to extract the body content of the ICNS file into BufferedImage objects.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use my [TwelveMonkeys ImageIO](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#icns---apple-icon-image) library to read ICNS format, if you like. However, *"It turns out I cannot use that library within my organization"* doesn't sound like a programming issue. **Why** is it that you can't use commons-imaging?

Comment: Thank you for replying @haraldK. I cannot use apache-imaging because of licensing issue of one of it's sub modules.

Comment: I strongly advise you to update the question with details about *what* issue do you have with the license, and specify *which* sub module has the issue. As it stands, your question is vague. It still might be closed as off-topic for Stack Overflow though. Maybe https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ is a better fit. Try to ask there. :-)